# Visual Basic - How to send values in a subroutine back to the main program?

Tags: vb.net, subroutine

I have an assignment in Visual basic I don't know how to do.  I am to create 2 sub routines and 1 function that send values back to main calling program.  The main program populates the combobox and displays information in the listbox and that is all.

The first sub takes a selected entry from the combobox which is Name and ID.  The sub does the calculation and sends Name, ID, and Calculated Value back to calling program.

My question is how do I send these 3 values back to the main calling program?  I am assuming there is no byRef.  I apologize in advance if this is not a unique question but I haven't been able to find an answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Make all three functions

Comment: I am not allowed to, it has to be a sub

Comment: And those three values have to be returned in one sub

Comment: It sounds like you only need to return Calculated Value form your function.  The calling code would already have access to Name and ID.

Comment: How do I send the calculated Value though?

Comment: And I have to send the three values so the program knows what one was selected so it can send appropriate information to the other sub and function

Comment: Why would you assume there is no ByRef?  If you want to get a value back from a Sub, then you would have to use ByRef.  The Function can just return the value using the Return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "my assignment", you are talking about school, I would assume the point of the assignment is for you to learn and understand passing parameters to subroutines.  In that case, please read up on [ByVal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2b185t2.aspx) vs [ByRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c84t73c2.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with three properties and pass that around.

Comment: I haven't learnt either of those things yet.  He also said we aren't allow to use any class variables so I don't know if that's ruled out.